# Listeners inside detectTapGestures only ever get the first variable value - Other Compose views update as expected

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to copy a text passed into a Compose view on long press. It is not directly the value, but instead, it's something like `itemText ?: "Fallback"`. The thing is, the value of the parameter `text` inside the `onLongPress` lambda is *never* updated. Only the first value gets taken. This was both evaluated debugging & using toasts to display the value.

Also tried out many other things, including not using `remember`, using a function instead of directly using `itemText ?: "Fallback"`, etc.

Inside the Button's onClickListener, the value is always up to date.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a Compose bug in there somewhere? As I am guessing that it's a bug, I have reported it to the issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/216160969

```kotlin
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ComposeTutoriaTheme {
                Sample()
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Sample() {
    var itemText: String? by remember {
        mutableStateOf(null)
    }

    Column {
        Button(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp, bottom = 20.dp),
            onClick = {
                itemText = if (itemText == null) {
                    "Tomato"
                } else {
                    null
                }
            }
        ) {
            Text(text = "Tap to toggle")
        }

        GroceryItem(text = itemText ?: "Fallback")
    }
}

@Composable
fun GroceryItem(text: String) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onLongPress = {
                    Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            )
        },
        text = text
    )

    Button(
        onClick = {
            Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    ) {
        Text(text = "Button to copy from, onClick")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behavior.

[`Modifier.pointerInput`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/input/pointer/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).pointerInput(kotlin.Any,kotlin.coroutines.SuspendFunction1)) remembers all variables, just like `remember` does. This is done so as not to interrupt touch handling during any recomposition.

And same as with `remember`, you can pass any parameters you need to keep track of as a `key` parameter instead of `Unit`:

```
Modifier.pointerInput(text) {
    detectTapGestures(
        onLongPress = {
            Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    )
},
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved it! I really don't get the reason why it is that way - The documentation mentions `key1`, but as far as I can tell does not mention that it "remembers all variables" :(. I can only guess, but I think many people will stumble across this

Comment: @CarstenHagemann I'm agree that documentation isn't that clear at this point. Actually it captures the lambda with all the variables inside. You can look through the source code and see that `key` is passed to `LaunchedEffect` and it in turn passes it to `remember`.